# How can I create null class object in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, class, object, kotlin

In java, we can declare a null class object like this

```
VideoRecord videoRecord;
```

After that, we can check if it is null or not

```
if (videoRecord == null){
    videoRecord = new VideoRecord();
}
```

I am new to Kotlin and I would like to do the same thing in Kotlin. I have tried this code below.

```
lateinit var videoRecord1:VideoRecord

if (videoRecord1 == null){
    videoRecord1 = VideoRecord()
}
```

But it gives me a warning like the condition `videoRecord1 == null` is always false. How can I make the same thing in Kotlin?

Comment: You have to use the `?` in order to explicitly make a variable nullable, like `var videoRecord1: VideoRecord?`. Currently, the `videoRecord1` cannot be `null`, which makes the warning correct.

Comment: If it is null I am going to create an object and I will run a different method after I create an object from class I will run another method @Lino

Answer (score 5):

```
var videoRecord: VideoRecord? = null
```

you can initial its variable like this

nullable reference : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, e.g. lazy initialization then this may be more suitable for you than the answer given by [andika_kurniawan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64334056/5515060):

```
val videoRecord: VideoRecord by lazy { VideoRecord() }
```

This will lazily initialize `videoRecord` the *first time* it is accessed.

The advantage of this way is that you don't have to check for `null` when accessing `videoRecord`, because it **cannot** be `null`. This simplifies the usage of that variable significantly. Additionally you can mark `videoRecord` as `val`, meaning it is `final`, so it cannot be overwritten.

The example shown by @andika_kurniawan:

```kotlin
var videoRecord: VideoRecord? = null
```

Has some caveats and disadvantages:

1. You *always* have to check that `videoRecord` is not `null` (and it gets tedious), see this example:

   ```kotlin
   if (videoRecord != null) {
       videoRecord.callAMethod()
   }
   ```

   The above **will not** work, because `videoRecord` defined as nullable, so you need to use the `!!` operator to tell kotlin that you're sure that the variable is not null:

   ```kotlin
   if (videoRecord != null) {
       videoRecord!!.callAMethod()
   }
   ```

   You can of course use other idioms, like the null-safe operator `?.`

   ```kotlin
   videoRecord?.callAMethod()
   ```

   Or the already mentioned `!!` operator (which throws an exception when it is `null`) but this time without a `null` check:

   ```kotlin
   videoRecord!!.callAMethod()
   ```

   You may also use local variables, which simplify the usage (a little bit):

   ```
   val videoRecord = videoRecord
   if (videoRecord != null) {
       videoRecord.callAMethod()
   }
   ```
2. The variable is *not* `final`, so nothing stops you from doing this somewhere in your code:

   ```kotlin
   videoRecord = null
   ```
3. You have to initialize it *somewhere*, so if you have multiple methods accessing `videoRecord` you first have to initialize it if it hasn't already been, introducing unnecessary redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

In kotlin, declaration of variable is different from java as kotlin is null safe language. You have to declare variable nullable. Only then its value can be null.

You can declare it as below

```
var videoRecord: VideoRecord? = null
```

To access nullable values you have to use !! or ? with variable names.